# Get CSS position attribute gwt

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

Is there any way to get the value of the **position** attribute of a widget in GWT?
I already have tried `widget.getElement.getStyle().getPosition()` but it always returns an empty String.
Thanks

Comment: Does the widget has a `position` applied to it directly? (inline style) or is it applied through a class?

Comment: It's through a class I forgot to say that it's a computed style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a native method that uses `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle`.

```
public static native String getComputedPosition(Element element) /*-{

    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null)["position"];
}-*/;
```

This works with most modern browsers.
Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-OverrideAndComputed

Comment: Note that different browsers need different code though… IE8 and older (or IE9+ in their IE8, IE7 or Quirks modes) don't have `defaultView` or `getComputedStyle`. http://caniuse.com/getcomputedstyle You also should use `$doc` instead of `document`, or you could use `$wnd` instead of `$doc.defaultView`. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

`getStyle().getPosition()` will return you an empty string if the widget is not attached to the **DOM**. In that case no matter what method you use it will always return empty string or null.

Make sure that widget is attached to DOM then `getStyle().getPosition()` will work just fine

Comment: Yes it's attached to the DOM